# R: Mutiply 4-dimensional array with two dimensional matrix efficiently

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a four dimensional array, where dim1 & dim 2 represent height and width and dim3 represents a Location in my dataset. I have a fourth dimension which represents a time factor.

```
LocA<-c("NewYork","Rio","Tokio") 
Time<-c("Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4","Y5","Y6","Y7","Y8")
assign("Mat",floor(array(0,c(100,100,length(LocA),length(Time)),dimnames=list(NULL,NULL,LocA,Time))))
```

Now I want to work with a Leslie-Matrix and Multiply every Element of dim1-3 with the 2d-Leslie matrix.

My setup for this is:

```
TimeLeslie<-array(0,c(8,8))
TimeLeslie[1,]<-c(0,0.3,0,0,0,0,0,0)
TimeLeslie[2,]<-c(0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0,0)
TimeLeslie[3,]<-c(0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0,0)
TimeLeslie[4,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0.3,0,0,0)
TimeLeslie[5,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0,0)
TimeLeslie[6,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3,0)
TimeLeslie[7,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3)
TimeLeslie[8,]<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.3)
TimeLeslie
Mat[,,,"Y1"]<-1000
```

I can achieve my desired outcome by using nested for loops:

```
for(i in 1:100){
  for(j in 1:100){
    for(loc in LocA){
     Mat[i,j,loc,]<- Mat[i,j,loc,]%*%TimeLeslie
    }
  }
}
```

However, is there a faster solution using vectorization. If so how to code it?

**EDIT:**
Seeing the complexity of the problem I reduced the number of dimensions by splitting the array into three.

```
for(loc in LocA){
assign(paste("Mat",loc,sep=""),floor(array(0,c(100,100,length(Time)),dimnames=list(NULL,NULL,Time))))
}
```

How can I go from here?

Comment: `timeLeslie` is an `8` times `8` matrix ..and you want to multiply `Mat[1,1,,] , Mat[1,2,,], ..., Mat[2,1,,], ...` by this `timeLeslie` correct?

Comment: That is correct. The first two dimensions represent x,y coordinates. The third one a location. The fourth one is a time component. The multiplication of every item oft `Mat[x,y,Location,]` with `timeLeslie` should "move" 30% of samples found in "Y1" to "Y2", 30% of "Y2" to "Y3" and so on